# Error using for loop with Ejs data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

iI have checked other questions but none have the same issues I am having and so the solutions do not apply.

Here is a sample of the code I am using :

```
            <script>
              var dataLength = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(userData.length) %>');

           for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++){
            console.log(i);  //output = 0 
         console.log(JSON.stringify('<%- userData[i].latitude %>'));
          var latitude = JSON.parse('<%- userData[i].latitude %>');
          var longitude = JSON.parse('<%- userData[i].longitude %>');

          var co = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: co, map: map});
         var image = 'assets/images/location.png';
         marker.setIcon (image);

           }

        }
      </script>
```

This throws an error : "i is not defined".  Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You're logging uppercase I. Also, I don't use ejs much but aren't these ejs strings interpolated on the server? Also, that's not valid json to parse. What are you trying here?

Comment: stack overflow will not allow me use lower case I while typing. I am getting all user data from a database and sending It to the frontend using Ejs . that's what then " userData" basically is.  It contains an array of all user data . Then I loop through It and get the specific data I want.  This works fine outside of the <script></script>.  When I use the Ejs functions directly in the html body

Comment: That's bizarre... what do you mean "won't let you type a lower case i"? I see, so this is in the template that's being served. Is this a JS error or an ejs error?

Comment: This is a js error because I have this exact same for loop running on another page and that works just fine.  I think It is because I am calling the Ejs variable inside <script> </script> . But for what I'm doing, the practical way is to do It in the <script>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop with `i` will execute on client-side, but not on server-side. Hence i is not available while the ejs is executing.

I see you are trying to iterate through userData to get lat, lng. Why don't you try the following?

```
<script>
  var userData = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(userData) %>');

  for(var user of userData){
    var latitude = JSON.parse('<%- user.latitude %>');
    var longitude = JSON.parse('<%- user.longitude %>');
    // handle latitude, longitude
  }

</script>
```

Comment: where will the declaration of `i` come from? I see you use It but It isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet, as you are iterating on userData array, you have the user reference.